# Refresh Parent window on close

Tags: javascript

I'm not a php expert but willing to learn :)
I know this subject has been discussed before with several solutions, I've tried almost all suggested scripts like : parent.window.location.reload(true);      and     window.onunload = refreshParent;

Please help! This SAVE routine is a popup window, I would like it to save to the database, which it does, but would like it to Auto-refresh the parent window I'm on, without having to press F5

I've tried the scripts in many places, keep getting white pages on the popup, I guess it's infinitely looping...

Question : what code and where to insert it please?
Thx
Sandra

```
sub save_editing
{

    $error_message = "";
    $new_line = "";

    #  Find Record
    ###########################
    $row_counter = 1;
    until ($row_counter > $number_of_records)
    {

    #  Not Record to Edit
    ###########################
    $form{'row_number'} != $row_counter and do{

    foreach (@table_fields)
    {$new_line .= qq~$data_hash{$row_counter}{$_}|~;}

    $new_line .= "\n";
    };#end do


    #  Record to Edit
    ###########################
    $form{'row_number'} == $row_counter and do{

    $counter = 1;

    foreach (@table_fields)
    {
    $requiredfield{$counter} and !$form{$counter} and $error_message .= qq~<b>$_</b> is a required field, and nothing has been entered.<br>~;
    $uniquefield{$counter} and !$form{$counter} and $error_message .= qq~<b>$_</b> is a unique, required field, and nothing has been entered.<br>~;

    # Check Required Status
    #######################################
    $uniquefield{$counter} and $form{$counter} and do{

    foreach $keys (keys %data_hash)
    {$data_hash{$keys}{$_} eq $form{$counter} and $keys != $form{'row_number'} and $error_message .= qq~<b>$_</b> is required to be a unique field, and has been found in the database at line $keys.<br>~;}

    };#end required field do


    # Remove New Lines
    ######################################
    $form{$counter} =~ (s/\r\n/\<br\>/g);

    # Create New Line By Adding Next Field
    ######################################
    $new_line .= qq~$form{$counter}|~;

    $counter++;
    }

    $new_line .= "\n";
    };#end do

    $row_counter++;
    }#end until

    # Save if No Errors
    ######################################
    !$error_message and do{
    open (FILE, ">$data_file");
    print FILE qq~$new_line~;
    close (FILE);
    chmod(0666,"$data_file");
    $save_message = qq~<b>Record $form{'row_number'} Editing Has Been Saved</b><P><script>window.close()</script>~;
    };

    # end save to file
    # Report Errors if Present, Return 
    ######################################
    $error_message and do{

    $save_message = qq~Record $form{'row_number'} Editing Has <b>Not</b> Been Saved. Please correct the following:<P>$error_message<P>~;

    };# end save to file

    &load_db;

}#end save editing

1;
```

Comment: That's not PHP.

Comment: I did mention I'm not an expert :) can someone guide me please. thx